# NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record

Tags: java, spring-data, netty, spring-data-redis, amazon-elasticache

I'm using Redis Spring Data (`1.8.9.RELEASE`) with Lettuce (`4.5.0.Final`) as underlying Redis driver. It's using netty of version `4.1.29`.

We're using Redis ElastiCache with Encryption-In-Transit and Encryption-At-rest enabled.

I'm getting below error. I saw a post related to netty's `NotSslRecordException` in which [suggested cause](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/378) is mismatch of http and https. But we tcp connection with elasticache.

```
Caused by: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisException: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to xxx-redis-xxx-0002-002.-redis-xxx.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.LettuceFutures.await(LettuceFutures.java:130)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:96)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.ClusterFutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(ClusterFutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:117)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy344.hgetall(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.hGetAll(LettuceConnection.java:2887)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to qbo-pprd-redis-rpg-0002-002.qbo-pprd-redis-rpg.jtrqdt.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.cluster.PooledClusterConnectionProvider.lambda$getConnectionAsync$7(PooledClusterConnectionProvider.java:344)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:822)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:797)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.AbstractRedisClient.lambda$null$0(AbstractRedisClient.java:331)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at com.lambdaworks.redis.SslConnectionBuilder$SslChannelInitializer$2.userEventTriggered(SslConnectionBuilder.java:212)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:329)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:315)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:307)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslUtils.handleHandshakeFailure(SslUtils.java:319)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1573)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.setHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1542)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1183)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:628)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:563)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 17000000242d455252206d6178206e756d626572206f6620636c69656e747320726561636865640d0a15000000020100
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 17000000242d455252206d6178206e756d626572206f6620636c69656e747320726561636865640d0a15000000020100
```

Comment: Since i'm not familiar with Redis Spring Data and Lettuce I'm not much of help there but what I can tell you is that the underlying netty SslHandler expected a ssl-handshake but received something that's not a ssl-handshake (the client/server probably didn't try to establish a connection via ssl). https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/96feca1d23ec5c31c8c692293241911de88ae8d0/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java#L1200

Answer (score 21):

```
$ printf '17000000242d455252206d6178206e756d626572206f6620636c69656e747320726561636865640d0a15000000020100' | xxd -r -p | xxd
00000000: 1700 0000 242d 4552 5220 6d61 7820 6e75  ....$-ERR max nu
00000010: 6d62 6572 206f 6620 636c 6965 6e74 7320  mber of clients 
00000020: 7265 6163 6865 640d 0a15 0000 0002 0100  reached.........
```

Comment: what does this explain?

Comment: @mike01010 it is not an SSL handshake, but a plaintext in bytes format

Answer (score 1):

From thread stack, it appears you are using Spring Data Redis in conjunction with Lettuce Library.

While creating LettuceClientConfiguration, you need to tell Client to use SSL by setting this option useSSL();
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce/LettuceClientConfiguration.html#isUseSsl--

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have set the client to use SSL - lettuceConnectionFactory.setUseSsl(true). This issue is intermittent.