# NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS when sending HTTPS requests from a dockerized Scala app

Tags: java, docker, scala, ubuntu, ssl

I'm using Scala 2.11 and Dispatch 0.11.3 for sending http requests, Docker version 20.10.21 with Ubuntu 18.04 inside the container. Http requests are working fine when the app is launched without Docker on my local machine.

From inside docker container, http requests seem to work, but not https, and the following exception is being returned:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: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
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:858)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:310)
org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Until few days ago, requests were working just fine, no any changes or updates to any libs/tools were done. Old containers that were built few days ago also work fine.

I have very little knowledge of SSL. Can anybody advise how to find the reason and where to look further to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996554/notsslrecordexception-not-an-ssl-tls-record)

Comment: @GaëlJ I don't think it does, it doesn't help me to troubleshoot the issue. Also, I can't decrypt the error cause as proposed in the most popular answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by Ubuntu security update 5719-1. Apparently, OpendJDK now uses TLS 1.3 by default which is not supported by the Dispatch http library. It was decided to stick to Ubuntu's version before the update. Now we are planning to upgrade Scala and switch the Dispatch library to the one that supports TLS 1.3.